# Are the Mac OS X GUI and a Terminal session peers?

Tags: macos, mac, unix, terminal

I'm trying to get to grips with UNIX.

If I open up a Terminal in Mac OS X and run `w`, I see

```
USER       TTY
myusername console
myusername s001
```

(I don't know if "session" is the right term)

- I assume that `s001` is my Terminal session. Does `console` represent the entire Mac OS X GUI's session?
- The GUI session is obviously fancier and more complex, but is it a peer to the Terminal session conceptually?
- What are the GUI session's stdin / stdout / stderr hooked up to?

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/480763/ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone with more knowledge about this can feel free to correct me here!

- `s001` is your TTY. It's the terminal you're connected to the machine via.
- The GUI is, as you said, a means of logging on to the server, and therefore it shows as `console`. It does have `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr`
- stdin is typically NULL. stdout and stderr go to the console log, in `/Library/Logs/Console/*your_uid*/console.log`

Comment: So does console "own" ttys001 or are they peers as far as the UNIXy core is concerned?

Comment: @f100: No. `console` and `ttys001` are both device names, listed in `/dev`. The first line in the `w` output is indicating that there's a login session with `/dev/console` as its "controlling terminal". The second line indicates there's a login session with `/dev/ttys001` as its controlling terminal. tty devices are normally opened in order, starting at `ttys000`. If you close all open terminals and open a new one, it will usually get `ttys000`, since it's free again.

Comment: @f100: i.e., "no, console doesn't own ttys001". I suppose the answer to the second part of your question is "yes," insofar as they are both "merely" terminal devices connected to login sessions. However, the login session that has `console` as its controlling terminal is special in that that login session is created when you login at the Mac OS X login window.

Answer (score 2):

The "console" does indeed refer to the primary session of an OS X machine. It doesn't need to be graphical. Try entering `>console` as your username at the login window some time.

Comment: So does "console" mean the first session? Or is it a special session reserved for the keyboard/screen that are physically attached to the computer? In UNIX in general, must there always be a "console" session open?

Comment: In OSX it's the physical terminal. I believe it's the same in some other UNIXes such as Solaris, but not so in linux. There you are allocated tty# depending on which of the physical terminals you log in to.

Comment: `console` is the name of the `/dev/console` device. The first line of `w` output is indicating that there's a login session with `/dev/console` as its controlling terminal. According to `sudo lsof /dev/console`, `launchd` has it open. I was under the impression that writing to `/dev/console` just wrote to the console log file, but I haven't been able to verify it produces changes in any logs I examined.